# How to attach a pdf to intent to send (to email, dropbox, etc) in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent

Hey so I save my pdf in external data storage. Eg:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/file.pdf"
```

Then, I try to attach it to intent to send:

```
        File attachment = this.getFileStreamPath(fileDirectory + "/" + fileName);


        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(attachment);

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("mailto:"), "text/plain"); // I have also tried "application/pdf"

        emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Calc PDF Report");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " PDF Report");

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
```

and im getting the error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/file.pdf contains a path separator
```

I am thinking it is something wrong with were I am saving my file, but can't find any examples that are up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share a file as an email attachment using intent, you need to use a FileProvider.

```java
/**
 * Generate file content and returns uri file
 */
public static Uri generateFile(Context context) {
  File pdfDirPath = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "pdfs");
  pdfDirPath.mkdirs();

  File file = new File(pdfDirPath, "attachment.pdf");
  file.deleteOnExit();

  Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".file.provider", file);
  FileOutputStream os = null;
  try {
    Logger.info("Generate file " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    document.writeTo(os);
    document.close();
    os.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return uri;
}

private void share(Context context) {
  Uri uri = generateFile(context);

  final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
  emailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Send something");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "You receive attachment");
  emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

  startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

In your app add the file provider definition:

```xml
AndroidManifest.xml

<application
  android:name=".DemaApplication"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  <provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.file.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
             android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
  </provider>
  ...
</application>
```

```
provider_path.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="internal_files"
        path="/"/>
    <!--<external-path name="external_files" path="./files"/>-->
</paths>
```

At last but not least, you need to specify the file provider path (where are your files). I hope this helps. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send), the official documentation about how to send email and attachment with intent.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but also look at CommonsWare answer (if you want a better understanding), as it provides a lot of "hooks" to google so can understand the above code better and learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1: `getFileStreamPath()` does not support subdirectories and is not related to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), where your file resides.

Problem #2: `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0, as your app will crash with a `FileUriExposedException`. To fix this and Problem #1, use `FileProvider` to set up a `content` `Uri` that you can use for `EXTRA_STREAM`.

Problem #3: `ACTION_SEND` does not use a "data" `Uri` (i.e., your `"mailto:"` should not be there).

Problem #4: The MIME type of a PDF is not `text/plain` — as your comment notes, use `application/pdf`.

Problem #5: `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated on Android 10 and higher, and you will not be able to write files there. Consider using `getExternaFilesDir(null)` (called on a `Context`) for a better location that works without permissions and on more Android OS versions.

> can't find any examples that are up-to-date

The documentation covers [the use of `ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send).